Named entity recognition (NER) task on a large dataset from a data frame column using chunking, and append to results to the original data frame
I want to perform a NER task on a column of a dataframe. The shape of the dataframe is:
import pandas
    df.shape()
    (1312, 12)

Now the column I wanted to use is called the TEXT column for the NER task. So I have attempted to first convert the column and all the row values to a single string. The code snippet:
# Convert to string type 
df['TEXT']=df['TEXT'].astype('string')
non_empty_texts = [text.strip() for text in df['TEXT'] if text.strip()]
# Join the rows into a single string
joined_text =  '\n'.join(non_empty_texts)

After that, define the chunk size, split the joined_text into chunks, and process each chunk, and predict the entities using the given model.
# Define the chunk size 
chunk_size = 5000  

# Split the joined_text into chunks
chunks = [joined_text[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(joined_text), chunk_size)]

# Initialize an empty list to store entities
all_entities = []

# Process each chunk and extract entities
for chunk in chunks:
    entities = model.predict_entities(chunk, labels, threshold=0.5)
    all_entities.extend(entities)

Finally convert the list of dictionary into a dataframe:
# Convert the list of dictionaries to a DataFrame
output= pd.DataFrame(all_entities)

The issue is the shape of the output is (700,4) and the shape of the original data frame df is 13212. Therefore, merging makes no sense. The aim is, I need to have ID column in the original dataframe df, merged to the output dataframe
Any suggestions are much appreciated! Please let me know if you need more information!
